# How do you simply validate two textboxes at the same time in an if-else statement? (c#)

Tags: c#, validation

This is probably the simplest thing ever, but I'm a noob!

Currently, say I'm building a password/username if-else validator that gives you a message if you enter a valid username and password (they're stored in a one-dimensional array, and the passwords don't need to match with the usernames, just as long as you enter one of the passwords and usernames in the arrays), I do an if-else for both the password and the username like (this is a rushed example):

```
if{txtUsername.text = THE ARRAY}{ MessageBox.Show("Welcome ________") }
```

and I'd do the same for the password.

BUT...these conflicts...what if the password is right, but the username is wrong or any other conflicting variation. All the If-Else statements I make will just conflict.

How would I validate my password/username single dimensional arrays in a single if-else statement that will spit out a message like:

> "Hello (username entered from array)! your password checks out!"

or

> "Hello (username), we are sorry but that is the incorrect password!"
>
> "hello! please enter a username and password!"

or any other variation. I'm sure this is very simple which is why I am asking for a little hand!

---

Let's pretend my arrays are called

```
int[] passwords = {123,321,222};
string[] usernames = {"jon", "todd", "bob"};
```

and my textboxes are `txtUser` and `txtPass`

Comment: Is this just an example of the real issue? Because for security reasons, you should not inform the user whether the name or password was the incorrect field, because it makes brute force attacks easier.

Comment: Just an example! I'm currently studying, and I'd always lose marks because I kept on making a billion conflicting if-else statements rather than just make one simple straight forward if-else so i'm trying to work on this problem I have. Any example you have is welcome!

Comment: This associates all passwords with each other, all user names with each other, and does not associate users with passwords. If you want to associate a user with a password this is a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Your sole idea is to validate whether the entered credential is correct or not and not to let user know specifically which of the credential went wrong which let the hacker concentrate on that (either username or password).

You can just to validate

```
if (txtUsername.text = "value" && txtpasswd.text = "value")
//go on
else 
//keep trying or lock out after certain trial
```

Strange that you have credential stored in array but in that case you can do like

```
if(Array.IndexOf(yourusernamearray, txtUsername.text) > -1 && Array.IndexOf(yourpasswdarray, txtpasswd.text) > -1 )
```

Comment: it was as simple as an &&? wow! thanks. Just curious, rather than have "value", how can I make it so that it = whatever is in the array

Comment: If you want to know if a value is present in an array, you could use LINQ or a contains of some kind instead of equals.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into scaleability and other numerous problems presented by this design (I'll assumed the question is academic), your question should be framed more like: "How do I ensure that value x is present in an array and that value y matches the element in the same position in a second array? You'd want something like:

```
    public void WelcomeUser()
    {
        var userNames = new string[] { "jon", "todd", "bob" };
        var passwords = new int[] { 123, 321, 222 }; // integer passwords???
        var userLoc = Array.IndexOf(userNames, this.TxtUserName.Text);
        if(userLoc >= 0 && passwords[userLoc] == Convert.ToInt32(this.TxtPass.Text))
            MessageBox(String.Format("Welcome {0}!", userNames[userLoc]));
        else
            MessageBox("Bad username or password");
    }
```

Note that it is insufficient to simply check to see if hte password is present in the second array- assuming you want passwords tied to accounts, and not some strange scheme where any combination of any username and any password will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If the username is incorrect, you have no idea what password it was supposed to be.  That's a normal thing.  Also as Nikki mentioned,  you would wish to give the user a generic error to avoid a security issue.

Try this

```
using System.Linq;
var userIdx = usernames.ToList().FindIndex(x => x == txtUser.Text);
var passIdx = passwords.ToList().FindIndex(x => x == int.Parse(txtPass.Text));
```

Recommended more like this

```
if(userIdx < 0 || passIdx < 0)
    MessageBox.Show(Bad Credentials)
else if(passIdx == userIdx)
    MessageBox.Show(Welcome)
else
    MessageBox.Show(Bad Credentials)
```

Not recommended but closer to what is being asked.

```
if(userIdx < 0 || passIdx < 0)
    MessageBox.Show(Bad Credentials)
else if(userIdx < 0 && passIdx > -1)
    MessageBox.Show(Bad Password)
else if(userIdx > -1 && passIdx < 0)
    MessageBox.Show(Bad username)
else if(passIdx == userIdx)
    MessageBox.Show(Welcome)
else
    MessageBox.Show(Bad Credentials)
```